# Как скачать все письма с помощью FETCH по IMAP используя pycurl

Tags: python, curl, imap

Я пытаюсь получить все письма в директории IMAP с помощью pycurl.

К примеру таким образом я получаю список директорий:

```
import pycurl
import certifi

with open('mail.txt', 'wb') as f:
    c = pycurl.Curl()
    c.setopt(pycurl.CAINFO, certifi.where())
    c.setopt(c.URL, 'imaps://imap.example.com/')
    c.setopt(c.USERPWD, 'user@example.com:password')
    c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, f)
    c.perform()
    c.close()
```

Далее, мне необходимо получить все письма каждой дериктории. Это делается, с помощью команды `FETCH 1:*`
С помощью curl команда которая мне нужна выглядит следующим образом:

```
curl imaps://imap.example.com/ --user "user@example.com:password" -X "FETCH 1:* (BODY[TEXT])" --ssl --verbose
```

Насколько я понял, то параметр `-X` в pycurl это `POSTFIELDS`

Получается, что запрос вышенаписанной мною команды с помощью pycurl будет выглядеть так:

```
with open('mail.txt', 'wb') as f:
    c = pycurl.Curl()
    c.setopt(pycurl.CAINFO, certifi.where())
    c.setopt(c.URL, 'imaps://imap.example.com/INBOX')
    c.setopt(c.USERPWD, 'user@example.com:password')
    c.setopt(c.POSTFIELDS, 'FETCH 1:* (BODY[TEXT])')
    c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, f)
    c.perform()
    c.close()
```

Но данная комманда не работает, и возвращает все тот-же список директорий.
Если у кого-нибудь был подобный опыт, прошу подскажите что я делаю не так.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ на собственный вопрос. Согласно документации по libcurl API, параметр `-X` это не `POSTFIELDS` а `CUSTOMREQUEST`
https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html

То есть конечный код будет выглядеть так:

```
with open('mail.txt', 'wb') as f:
    c = pycurl.Curl()
    c.setopt(pycurl.CAINFO, certifi.where())
    c.setopt(c.URL, 'imaps://imap.example.com/INBOX')
    c.setopt(c.USERPWD, 'user@example.com:password')
    c.setopt(c.CUSTOMREQUEST, 'FETCH 1:* (BODY[TEXT])')
    c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, f)
    c.perform()
    c.close()
```

Другое дело, что curl возвращает только заголовки писем. Само тело писем он возвращает, только при включенном `c.setopt(c.VERBOSE, 1)`
И то, не пишет в файл, а просто принтит в терминал

Comment: А почему бы не воспользоваться imaplib?

Comment: imaplib не поддерживает proxy из коробки.
К тому-же, есть подозрения что curl работает значительно быстрее, нежели imaplib.

Comment: Мне кажется там сокеты, и можно обернуть их в прокси, посмотри в сторону PySocks

Comment: Я уже делал реализацию c помощью PySocks, я хочу использовать pycurl для того, что-бы сравнить производительность с imaplib.